# Change name property while serialization using datacontract serializer

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have class with name RSummary which  is being used to seriallize by DataContractSerializer.
It has property called submitted and Saved which are objects of class DInfo.
I have records in database in xml format which are of type RSummary.
While serializing those xml records I have some xml records(old records) in Database which are using DInfo class from namespace ABC.Domain.Contract.Base and some records(new records) from namespace ABC.Common.Contract.

```
namespace ABC.Domain.Contract.Base
{
    public class RSummary
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public DInfo Submitted { get; set; }
        public DInfo Saved { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ABC.Domain.Contract.Base
{
   public class DInfo
   {
      public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
      public UserRef User { get; set; }

   }
}
namespace ABC.Common.Contract
{
   public class DInfo
   {
      public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
      public UserRef User { get; set; }

   }
}
```

What can I do to make deserialization working for both type of records i.e. new and old. 
I tried like but no luck

```
namespace ABC.Domain.Contract.Base
{
    public class RSummary
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public ABC.Common.Contract.DInfo Submitted { get; set; }// new record should be parsed here
         [DataMember(Name = "Submitted")]
        public ABC.Domain.Contract.Base.DInfo SubmittedOld { get; set; }// old record should be parsed here
        public ABC.Common.Contract.DInfo Saved { get; set; }
         [DataMember(Name = "Saved")]
        public ABC.Domain.Contract.Base.DInfo SavedOld { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code which is used to deserialize is

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string typeName, string data)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(typeName != null);

            var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
            var ser = new DataContractSerializer(type, null, Int32.MaxValue, false, false, null, new SharedTypeResolver());
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);

        }
```

Here typeName is type of object which we are deserializing i.e RSummary

Comment: Can you edit your question to show examples of the old and new XML?